# How to use double digits in the Editext afterTextChanged?

Tags: java, android

I can't add double digits in Editext and calculate the final price. I don't have any problems with one digit numbers. but when I want to add two-digit numbers My app closed.

```
    edt_value.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edt_value.getText())){
                edt_value.clearFocus();
                txt_finalprice.setText(gl_price.toString());
            }else {
                if(getCurrentFocus() == edt_value) {
                    int value = Integer.parseInt(edt_value.getText().toString().trim());
                    int price = Integer.parseInt(txt_finalprice.getText().toString().trim());
                    txt_finalprice.setText(value * price + "$");
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: What is your exeption

Comment: @TamirAbutbul  This problem is due to the occurrence of a time lag before the second number entered.  But I wanna to know how can I control it?

Comment: This is a bit too general for me, please add your logcat error so I can help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may getting the calculated data which is out of integer range use `Double.parseDouble`instead of `Integer.parseInt`

**Update**

Here is the problem in this code:

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(edt_value.getText().toString().trim());
                    int price = Integer.parseInt(txt_finalprice.getText().toString().trim());
                    txt_finalprice.setText(value * price + "$");
```

you are getting price from txt_finalprice that is fine at first and then in the last statement your are setting value * price + "$" to txt_finalprice, now txt_finalprice has some number and $(for ex: 30$), when you type again something in edit text this time again you are converting `txt_finalprice` value to price, but this will raise an exception because txt_finalprice  contains $ and it cannot be converted to int.

You need to store `txt_finalprice` value to a variable.

Comment: No. This problem is due to the occurrence of a time lag before the second number entered.  But I wanna to know how can I control it?

Comment: can you share exception?

Answer (score 0):

```
 int finalValue = value * price;

 txt_finalprice.setText(string.valueof(finalValue)+ "$");
```